# Ghostscript: Upscaling very small eps to large jpg

Tags: jpeg, ghostscript, eps

I am working with ghostscript to rasterize eps files to jpg format. What I am struggling with and cant seem to see an obvious answer for is how to properly "upscale" an eps file with a very small bounding box. Example:

```
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 71 47
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 70.9961 46.0020
```

To a great deal more pixels than we have points represented there (i.e. 4 megapixels) with the dDEVICEWIDTH/HEIGHT option. Example gs invocation with relevant options we are using:

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dEPSFitPage -dJPEGQ=100 -dBATCH -r300 -g2458x1628 -sOutputFile=output.jpg input.eps
```

This results in a jpg with the desired pixel dimensions but it is highly pixelated, losing all of the detail of the vector. Ive experimented with the options from the ghostscript docs that seemed potentially relevant:

```
-r1000...
-dInterpolateControl=<-1 through 1000>
-dGraphicsAlphaBits=<1,2,4>
```

None of these seem to have any effect on the pixelation of the resulting jpg. This effect seems to directly correlate to the points represented by the bounding box i.e. one point == one pixel, any upscaling results in loss of quality / pixels.

I am confused by why this is. In my mind (such as it is) the vector information in the eps should be able to scale to an arbitrary number of pixels. Can it? Am I missing something obvious and silly?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to upscale the EPS to another EPS then convert that EPS to JPEG.

Comment: Went ahead and gave that a shot. All things being equal except for the output device I get a similar result except in eps form. Any ghostscript tricks that can get past the "transparency flattening" settings you know of? I think the issue is that since transparency isnt actually supported in raw ps all i get from ghostscript is the bitmap preview, so there doesnt seem to be a way to get at it. Unless we somehow interpreted the private illustrator data / file.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied the EPS file, so its difficult to pinpoint the problem, here's some thoughts:

1) Don't mess with the JPEG quality, and in fact, don't use JPEG. Write out to a lossless format like TIFF. That will prevent the JPEG quantisation from messing with teh output, and remove a possible problem.

2) Check the EPS to see if it contains an image. This seems the most likely problem to me. PostScript programs can contain image data as well as vector, if your EPS contains a low resolution image then nothing much is going to help you, the result is going to be limited by the number of image samples in the input.

Comment: Yeah thats interesting. I did not supply the eps because I was assuming theres nothing particularly special about it. Its a complex image with lots of gradients, but no actual image / raster data. I made an experimental one with just a very simple gradient circle in it at the same size and it seems to scale up just fine with no loss of quality. The file in question doesnt belong to me so Ill have to see if I can share it.

Comment: This seems to have to do with the  transparency settings when saving out the original file. I added as close to answer as Ive got. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Right, PostScript doesn't support transparency, so if you have transparency in the original, then it has to be converted to an image. I bet teh EPS file does contain image data, but it might be hard to tell, because PostScript is a programming language, so you can wrap it up in lots of different ways. As you say above, if that's the case then the damage is done bfore it gets to Ghostscript, and it can't undo it.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this has everything to do with the "transparency flattening" settings chosen when originally saving the file. I am using illustrator and these range from "low" to "complex" presets ("medium" being the default).

["Medium" settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFCDP.png)

["Complex" settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0INzZ.png)

In a very small eps with transparency effects saved with the default "medium" settings, the resulting raster ends up of very low quality and there doesnt seem to be anything ghostscript can do about it. If you choose "complex" the raster is of full quality / resolution. If you instead scale the artwork up to approximately the same number of points as you want pixels, the "medium" settings result in a raster of comparable quality to using the "complex" settings for the small one.

There does not appear (to me) to be anything that can be done to solve for this after the file is already created.